# Vuetify carousel interval

Tags: vue.js, timer, slider, vuetify.js, intervals

I'd like to build a vuetify carousel for my webste with different background pictures and different text elements but the **interval** does not work. Accoding to the vuetify website only the "The duration between image cycles. Requires the cycle prop." is required to make it work but it seems I have a different problem. I can't find a solution for my problem.

```
<!-- SHOW FROM SM to XL-->
  <v-carousel hide-delimiters class="hidden-xs-only">
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(content,i) in carouselContents"
      :key="i"
      :src="require('@/assets/index/' + content.imageSrc)"
      continuous="true"
      cycle="true"
      interval="1000"
      show-arrows-on-hover
    >
      <v-row
        align="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <v-col cols="12" xs="1" sm="1" md="1" lg="1" xl="1">
          <!-- TEXT DISTANCE FOR BIG DISPLAYS -->
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" xs="10" sm="10" md="10" lg="8" xl="7">
          <div class="white--text text-left mt-16 mb-8 text-h4 text-md-h3 text-lg-h3 text-xl-h2 font-weight-medium">
            <p> 
              {{ content.headline1 }}
            </p>
            <v-divider class="my-5"></v-divider>
            <p>
              {{ content.headline2 }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" xs="1" sm="1" md="1" lg="3" xl="4">
          <!-- TEXT DISTANCE FOR BIG DISPLAYS -->
        </v-col>
      </v-row>

      <v-row
        align="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <v-col cols="12" sm="1" md="1" lg="1" xl="1">
          <!-- TEXT DISTANCE FOR BIG DISPLAYS -->
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="10" md="10" lg="8" xl="7">          
          <div class="text-left">
            <p class="white--text text-subtitle-1 font-weight-medium"> 
            {{text2a}} <u>{{text2b}}</u> {{text2c}}
            </p>
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'Signup' }">
              <v-btn tile x-large color="white" class="my-5 black--text">
                <span>{{button1}}</span>
                <v-icon right>{{mdiPencilPlus}}</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </router-link>
          </div>
        </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="1" md="1" lg="3" xl="4">
            <!-- TEXT DISTANCE FOR BIG DISPLAYS -->
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>
```

...

```
  carouselContents: [
    {
      headline1: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_ABOVE",
      headline2: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_BELOW",
      imageSrc: "create.jpg",
    },
    {
      headline1: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_ABOVE",
      headline2: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_BELOW",
      imageSrc: "view.jpg",
    },
    {
      headline1: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_ABOVE",
      headline2: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_BELOW",
      imageSrc: "share.jpg",
    },
    {
      headline1: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_ABOVE",
      headline2: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_BELOW",
      imageSrc: "compare.jpg",
    },
    {
      headline1: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_ABOVE",
      headline2: "EXAMPLE_TEXT_BELOW",
      imageSrc: "build.jpg",
    },
  ],
```

It qould be great if someone could help me...

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ups, my mistake...

I needed to put the interval in the carousel tab and not the carousel-item tab...

```
  <v-carousel 
    hide-delimiters 
    class="hidden-xs-only"
      continuous="true"
      cycle="true"
      interval="1000"
      show-arrows-on-hover
   >
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(content,i) in carouselContents"
      :key="i"
      :src="require('@/assets/index/' + content.imageSrc)"
    >
```